# How to maintain sessionid across different thread groups

Tags: json, performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing API testing using JSON.
My Jmeter's TestPlan looks like below:

```
Test Plan 
   Thread Group 1 (run once) 
      - Login 
   Thread Group 2 (I will run this multiple times) 
      - Do some opeartion 
   Thread Group 3 (run once) 
      - Logout
```

I want to pass `sessionid` from Thread Group 1 to Thread Group 2 and 3.

Comment: Did you try to add a Cookie Manager at the level of the Test Plan instead of the Thread group ?

Answer (score 0):

To extract sessionId use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to pass a value to another thread group using **beanshell postprocessor listener element** in Jmeter

Beanshell code to save variable

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
JMeterUtils.setProperty("propname", "value");
```

Beanshell code to retrieve variable from another thread group

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
vars.put("localvariable", JMeterUtils.getProperty("propname"));
var testVar=vars.get("localvariable");
log.info("@ NEXT THREAD GROUP value="+testVar);
```

Code using `Jmeter's getprperty(),setproperty() API` to pass the values. Also you can use JMeter Plugins has Inter-Thread Communication.

hope this will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

[How to use Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide contains an example of sharing cookies between different thread groups, scroll down to `Advanced Examples` section.

If you "session" assumes cookie-based session you'll need to do the following:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to the Test Plan (or each thread group if you prefer)
2. Tell the Cookie Manager to save cookies as variables by setting `CookieManager.save.cookies` property to `true` in *jmeter.properties* file which  lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation or passing it as command-line argument as follows

   ```
   jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -n ... -t ... -l ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have only one Thread Group instead of three and add `CookieManager` to your Thread Group. Have a Loop Controller to run the operation multiple times.

Your test can be structured as:

```
Test Plan 
  Thread Group
  - Cookie Manager
  - Login 
  - Loop Controller (run this multiple times) 
    - Do some operation  
  - Logout
```